# Fredholm operators -- index

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, adjoint-operators, elliptic-operators

Atkinson's theorem states:

$T ∈ L(H)$ is a Fredholm operator if and only if T is invertible modulo compact perturbation, i.e. $TS = I + C_{1}$ and $ST = I + C_{2}$ for some bounded operator S and compact operators $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$.

$L(H)$= espace of linear and bounded operators.

Let $A$ and $B$ two fredholm operators. How to prove that $A\oplus B\ $  is a fredholm operator using the the Atkinson's theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dim}{\text{dim}}\newcommand{\codim}{\text{codim}}\newcommand{\Ind}{\text{Ind}}\newcommand{\Ker}{\text{Ker}}\newcommand{\Ran}{\text{Ran}}$Notice that $\Ker(A\oplus B) =  \Ker(A)\oplus \Ker(B)$, hence a finite dimensional space,  and
$\Ran(A\oplus B) =  \Ran(A)\oplus \Ran(B)$,
hence a finite co-dimensional space.  Therefore $A\oplus B$ is Fredholm and
$$
  \Ind(A\oplus B) = \dim(\Ker(A\oplus B)) - \codim(\Ran(A\oplus B)) = $$ $$ =
  \dim(\Ker(A)) +   \dim(\Ker(B)) - \codim(\Ran(A)) - \codim(\Ran(B)) = $$ $$ =
  \Ind(A) +   \Ind(B).
  $$

Now, since $\Ker(A^*)^\perp = \Ran(A)$, we have
$$
  \Ind(A) =   \dim(\Ker(A)) - \dim(\Ker(A^*)),
  $$
from where it follows that   $\Ind(A^*) =  -\Ind(A)$.

Comment: Thanks Ruy ! How can I prove it using the Atkinson's theorem?

Comment: Just notice that the direct sum of the pseudo inverses is a pseudo inverse for the direct sum operator.

Comment: I know that if $R$ and $C$ are respectively pseudo inverses of $A$ and $B$, than $R\oplus C$ is pseudo inverse of $A\oplus B$. But how to get  $(A\oplus B)(R\oplus C)$ to be equal to $I + K$, where is some compact operator?

Comment: You have
  $$
  I-(A⊕B)(R⊕C) =   (I-AR)⊕(I-BC),
  $$
  which is the direct sum of compact operators hence  a compact operator.

Comment: I understood now. Thanks you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I can see from your profile that you have not accepted any answers to your questions.  Do you know how does that work?  If not you may learn about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yeah, I just did it. Thanks!